# Entire blender is greyed out/highlighted.. or something

Tags: drivers, installation

I haven't been in blender for over a month now and when I started it up fo the first time in a while, the whole thing is like white/grey:

[image]

[image]

I get the feeling that it might be because my computer needs an update, but I can't update it because other applications don't work with the update.

So far I tried:

- Updating my graphics card (didn't work)
- Uninstall and Reinstalling blender (didn't work)
- Going through the blender settings to see if something was ticked on or off

I feel like it's an NVIDIA problem or maybe something outside the application that needs to be turned on/off (I had this problem before but I can't remember what I did to fix it)

Any ideas? :)

Comment: It looks fine to me, its just the theme you have set. Go into user pref and change the theme

Comment: I don't think it's the theme, I never changed it before and originally it looked like the basic blender layout (everything was much darker). Now, even the words are faded out. I did take your advice though and tried to reset it but still nothing.

Comment: That looks to me like an issue with the configuration of the GPU.

Comment: In your NVIDIA settings reset the desktop color settings.

Comment: @Sidar How? What does the desktop color have to do with the blender? :o

Comment: If it's not the theme, it must be some settings in your desktop configuration. I'm just assuming that if there is anything affecting your application it's either nvidia or some third party tool you might have installed.